# Understanding $A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How to understand the set complement? I need to understand it as I am working with this set on some topology problem.

$$A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)$$

I can imagine what is going on but is there a proper set theoretic approach to write it.

**My efforts**

$A$ is the complement of points like $$\{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{Q}, b\in \mathbb{Q}^c\}$$

So complement should look some thing like $\{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{Q}^c, b\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{R}, b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: Your solution is correct, though $\mathbb{Q}^c \cup \mathbb{Q}$ is considered twice.

Comment: What about "$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^\complement)$" is not "proper set theoretic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is correct and can be written more simply as

$$A=(\mathbb Q^C\times \mathbb R)\cup (\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q)$$

To prove the two sets are equal, you can easily prove that

$$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)\subseteq (\mathbb Q^C\times \mathbb R)\cup (\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q)$$ and $$(\mathbb Q^C\times \mathbb R)\cup (\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)$$ are both true statements.

Comment: Thanks!! I understand this so that means $(A\times B)\setminus (C\times D) $ will be equal to $C^c\times B\cup A\times D^c$

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Well, what you wrote is the more general result, yes, but the proof is the same.

Comment: But are not we getting $\mathbb{Q}\cup \mathbb{Q}^c$ twice in my solution? So I have to filter out these things by my own observation right?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Where did you get $\mathbb Q\cup\mathbb Q^c$ "twice"?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\mathbb{Q}^c \cup \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Where did you get $\mathbb Q^c\cup\mathbb Q$ "twice"? What do you even mean by that sentence?

Comment: So this is what I get in last  $\{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{Q}^c, b\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{R}, b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Now elements of type $(a,b)$ where $a\in Q^c$ and $b\in Q$ belongs to both sets in the union.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician First of all, those elements aren't in $\mathbb Q^c\cup\mathbb Q$, they are in $\mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q$. That's why I was confused. Second of all, so what if they do? That doesn't make the equality false. $\cup$ denotes "union", not "disjoint union".

Comment: You are right. I was bit confused. Thanks for your time.